# Dagger don't generate component for androidTest

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm facing a problema with the component dagger generation, I want to generate the component for androidTest, but when I build the project, the DaggerTestComponent it's not generated.

Component:

```
package com.test.feliperibeirosaruhashi.testingkotlindagger

import dagger.Component

@Component(modules = arrayOf(MockTestModule::class))
interface MockAppComponent {
  fun inject(mainActivityTest:MainActivityTest)
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
  compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"

  compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
  kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
  provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'


  kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"

  kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"


  androidTestCompile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"

  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$RUNNER_VERSION"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$RUNNER_VERSION"
  androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$MOCKITO_VERSION"

  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"


  androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:$DEXMAKER_VERSION"
  androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:$DEXMAKER_VERSION"
  androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:$DEXMAKER_VERSION"
}
```

I put the full project on github:
https://github.com/felipesaruhashi/TestingKotlinDagger

Comment: Why are you both `compile`ing and `androidTestCompile`ing dagger? If you have `compile`ed it, then it already will be included in `androidTestCompile` build.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by [an issue in kapt](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15459). The fix for it targets `1.0.7`, `1.1-Beta`.

As a temporary workaround (until fix gets released) one could move `MockAppComponent` and related sources in to `main` source set.